# Modifier Properties don't show up for a collection

Tags: modifiers, collections

I have a collection and inside there there are several objects. I want to add a modifier to all the objects in the collection, but I couldn't find the modifier properties when I select the collection. How do I get the modifier properties to show up?

[image: collection]

In another object that's separate from the collection, the modifier properties are shown:

[image: body object]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to make the **Modifiers Properties** Panel show up when you have a **Collection** selected.

While an object like a cube, curve and such (objects like cameras and lights can't have modifiers either) can have a modifier that affects its mesh data or other data like UVs, **Collections** are only a placeholder with functionality (like an empty, but without origin).

They them self do not contain data that could be affected by modifiers.

The idea of using a collection to apply modifiers to all its children, is itself not bad, and I believe used in other software, but in Blender you need to add a modifier to one of the child objects and then copy the modifier to all other children in the collection/selection.

**Solution:**

1. Add the modifier(s) to one object.
2. Select all objects you want to get the same modifier(s). If they are all children of a collection, you can <kbd>RMB</kbd> to **Select Objects** in the Collection and all its children will be selected.
3. Make sure the object with the modifiers is the last selected/active one (visible by having a brighter outline in the 3D View).
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and choose **Copy Modifiers**, as shown below:
   [image]

Now all the selected objects have the same modifiers.

Happy Blending